# Is there any way to see the txpool with infura and web3?

Tags: infura, txpool, web3.py

I'd like to get pending transactions information without running my own node. Is there any way to do that?

Something like [this](https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs) would work too, but they only seem to provide a fraction of the pending transactions they see.

Comment: Are you looking for that: https://etherscan.io/txsPending ?

Comment: That would be perfect if I could access it through their API.

Comment: I just saw that your post title includes web3. You cannot use web3 without having  a node running.

Comment: I've been using web3 with a third party (infura) node, as per the title. Most functionalities work, but not the txpool features, as it returns: "HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://mainnet.infura.io/<ClientID>"

Comment: Maybe you should ask the Infura community.

Answer (score 5):

The standard Infura endpoint does not allow you to do that. I would suggest to use [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com), you can create a free node and allows you to do it. I have a repo showing exactly that in python using web3.py
Find it [here](https://github.com/soos3d/Retrive-and-display-pending-transactions-Web3.py)

This is the main code to retrieve the hash of pending transactions in web3.py

```
# retrive pending transactions hash
pending_tx_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
pending_tx = pending_tx_filter.get_new_entries()     # this is a list object

# loop through the list of transcations and displays the tx hash
for hash in pending_tx:
    print('Hash of a Pending Transaction:' , web3.toHex(hash))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been creating "work-around" for this, but in the meanwhile I saw this - https://www.shawntabrizi.com/ethereum/using-web3-js-1-0-subscribe-and-infura-websockets-to-visualize-ethereum-transactions/ ( haven't tried it, yet ). Tell me if it is of any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool to get a visualisation of pending transaction.
There is not API however.

https://txpool.zengo.com/#0,24h